# Выгрузка метаданных из потока онлайн-радио

Tags: java, android

Пишу простенькое онлайн-радио для *Android*, не могу разобраться с выгрузкой метаданных (исполнитель, альбом и т.п.).

Пробовал подобный код:

```
metaRetriver = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetriver.setDataSource("http...адрес...");
try
{
    art = metaRetriver.getEmbeddedPicture();
    Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
    album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
    album.setText(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
    artist.setText(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
    genre.setText(metaRetriver.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    album.setText("Unknown Album");
    artist.setText("Unknown Artist");
    genre.setText("Unknown Genre");
}
```

ругается на строчку с объявлением адреса.

Где-то прочитал, что эта *фича* не работает в текущих версиях *android*. Далее пробовал разобраться с кодом [по ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970548/).

Откуда там берется адрес сайта, с которого запускается поток?

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, `MediaMetadataRetriever` не работает с URL, только с файлами.
Я для своего радио использовал библиотеку [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever)

Вот пример работы с ней. Получение названия текущей композиции.

```
private String getCurrentTrackTitle() {
    final FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
    mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(getStreamUrl());
    final Metadata metadata = mediaMetadataRetriever.getMetadata();
    mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
    return metadata.getString("StreamTitle");
}
```